# How to jump from Planning to Monitoring of the same job in Control-M

Tags: shortcut, control-m

Fellow Control-M admins,

I often face this issue:

1. I open Control-M
2. I inspect Planning domain
3. I find a job in Planning domain
4. I want to see how the job executed i.e. see the current job in Monitoring domain.
5. I go to Monitoring domain
6. I open "All jobs" viewpoint
7. I search for the job by name (angry, because I forgot to copy the job name)

Is there any shortcut to be taken when searching for the same job in a different domain? Thanks.

**EDIT:**
With [Mark's help](https://stackoverflow.com/a/65496457/10446284) I found that pressing <kbd>Alt</kbd> followed by <kbd>F</kbd> as File, <kbd>Z</kbd> for Domains and finally <kbd>M</kbd> for monitoring.

These keyboard tricks however *don't solve my problem* which aims for **targeting instaces of planned jobs in Monitoring domain**.

Answer (score -1):

Given that chain, there's not really anything you can do to speed things up. There are shortcut keys though;

From Home, do Alt+F and hit M to open monitoring.

Full list of shortcuts -

https://documents.bmc.com/supportu/9.0.20/help/Main_help/en-US/index.htm#95147.htm